# Youtube iv_load_policy and controls params confilct

Tags: android, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm displaying a youtube video in an android app using iframe embed method using the following code:

```
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hifarzyF8GQ?iv_load_policy=1&controls=1" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="200" 
    allowscriptaccess="always" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true">
    </iframe>
```

I want to display the video annotations and the video controls in the same time using `iv_load_policy=1&controls=1`.

But there seems to be a conflict between these two youtube parameters in the mobile app environment, because both features are not working together in the same time, instead I have to set one param to 1 and the other to 0 to make only one of them to function, if both equal 1 then "controls" dominates.

Any solution for this?
Or at least for any method that can allow the user to make the youtube video Full Screen, as I am interested the most in showing the Full Screen button out of all the controls.

Answer (score 0):

base on the document:

> [**iv_load_policy**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#iv_load_policy)
>
> **Setting the parameter's value to 1 causes video annotations to be shown by default**, whereas setting to 3 causes video annotations to not be shown by default. **The default value is 1**.

For the controls:

> [**controls**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls)
>
> This parameter indicates whether the video player controls are displayed. For IFrame embeds that load a Flash player, it also defines when the controls display in the player as well as when the player will load.
>
> **Note**: The parameter values 1 and 2 are intended to provide an identical user experience, but **controls=2** provides a performance improvement over **controls=1** for IFrame embeds. Currently, the two values still produce some visual differences in the player, such as the video title's font size. However, when the difference between the two values becomes completely transparent to the user, the default parameter value may change from **1** to **2**.

According to this [note](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/92710?hl=en), Annotations do not appear on **custom YouTube chromeless players, or on mobile, tablet and TV devices**.

For the Fullscreen change `allowfullscreen="true"` to `allowfullscreen`

Comment: In my case Annotations show up when  `iv_load_policy=1&controls=0`

Comment: don't set any values to the control and check if the default value will still persist or make your control value to '2'